# How to select <lightning-input type=toggle via the name property using querySelector

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a toggle input:

```
<lightning-input type="toggle"
                 id="consent"
                 name="consent"
                 checked={consent}
                 ></lightning-input>
```

And I want to access it using `querySelector` using its `name` property:

```
const element = this.template.querySelector("[name='consent']");
console.log(element); // always null
console.log(element.checked);
```

But `element` is always `null`

**Questions**

1. Why does it work?
2. What am I doing wrong?
3. How can I successfully use `querySelector` to get the element and the `checked` property?

Answer (score 3):

We had the similar issue when trying to implement a form and submit the form on click of submit button:

the problem is that the name attribute is not placed on the lightning-input element but on the internal input element. So we are trying to access component internals which is prevented by Lockerservice.

The alternative is to access the element value by defining data attributes:

.html

```
<template>
<lightning-input type="toggle"
             id="consent"
             name="consent"
             data-name = "consent"
             data-checked = {checked}
             checked={checked}
             message-toggle-active=""
             message-toggle-inactive=""
             variant="label-hidden"
             onchange={chandeHandler}
             label="consent"
             ></lightning-input>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @track checked = true;
    chandeHandler() {
        const element = this.template.querySelector("[data-name='consent']");
        console.log(element); // always null
       console.log(element.checked);
     }
}
```

Code sample on [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/rYX7jH4_F/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

you can use data- attribute if you want to query it like that

```
<lightning-input type="toggle"
                 data-id="name"
                 label="test"
                 name="consent"
                 checked={consent}
                 message-toggle-active=""
                 message-toggle-inactive=""
                 variant="label-hidden"
                 ></lightning-input>
```

JS

```
var element = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input[data-id='name']");
console.log(element); // always null
console.log(element.checked);}
```

though i dont know why name dont work